# How to write foreign keys in many-to-many rich join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I am trying to create many-to-many rich join between AdminUser and Section with join table as SectionEdit. That is created by generating model. Inside create_section_edits, we write

```
 create_table :section_edits do |t|
    t.integer :admin_user_id
    t.integer :section_id
    t.timestamps
    t.string :summary
end
```

Is there any difference in between using `:admin_user_id` and `"admin_user_id"`? Same goes for the  other primary keys. admin_user_id is foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but it is better practice to use the symbol `:admin_user_id`

As an alternative consider:

```
create_table :section_edits do |t|
    t.references :admin_user, index: true
    t.references :section, index: true
    t.string :summary
    t.timestamps
end
```

Notice this way that you can index the foreign keys by adding `index: true`

Reference:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-references

Comment: ok, thanks. I asked this because when we create table, we write columns as "column_name". So I felt that using "column_name" and :column_name in different situations is confusing.

Comment: I agree. Thats why I prefer `t.references` because it is the least confusing. As soon as I see it I know it is a foreign key for an association.

Answer (score 0):

It should be same in this scenario.